# Retreive Xpath for google search links

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, xpath, automation

I am writing a python selenium scrip to try and extract the URL links for LinkedIn profiles in a google search but I am having problems narrowing down my XPath to only returning the search results links on google.

```
linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="yuRUbf"]//a[@href]')
for linkedin_url in linkedin_urls:
    url = linkedin_url.get_attribute("href")
    print(url)

    driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)
```

The results from linkedin_urls give me

```
https://uk.linkedin.com/in/roxana-andreea-popescu
https://uk.linkedin.com/in/tunjijabitta
https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=bxjhX4uGC4_ykgXl9pu4Bw&q=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22Software+Developer%22+AND+%22London%22&oq=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22Software+Developer%22+AND+%22London%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFDMZFjhZmCwZ2gAcAB4AIABLogBsAGSAQE0mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjL-dn4huDtAhUPuaQKHWX7BncQ4dUDCA0#
https://www.google.com/search?q=related:https://uk.linkedin.com/in/tunjijabitta&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji3qP_huDtAhWAZxUIHTyfAO4QHzABegQIBhAH
https://uk.linkedin.com/in/janomer
https://uk.linkedin.com/in/josephcoker
https://uk.linkedin.com/in/sebemin
https://uk.linkedin.com/in/vicki-marshall-b7433827
https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=bxjhX4uGC4_ykgXl9pu4Bw&q=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22Software+Developer%22+AND+%22London%22&oq=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22Software+Developer%22+AND+%22London%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFDMZFjhZmCwZ2gAcAB4AIABLogBsAGSAQE0mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjL-dn4huDtAhUPuaQKHWX7BncQ4dUDCA0#
https://www.google.com/search?q=related:https://uk.linkedin.com/in/vicki-marshall-b7433827&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji3qP_huDtAhWAZxUIHTyfAO4QHzAFegQIARAH
https://uk.linkedin.com/in/andreibodnar
https://www.google.com/search?q=related:https://uk.linkedin.com/in/andreibodnar&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji3qP_huDtAhWAZxUIHTyfAO4QHzAGegQIBxAH
https://uk.linkedin.com/in/dmrlawson
https://uk.linkedin.com/in/jack-gilbert-541a251b
https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=bxjhX4uGC4_ykgXl9pu4Bw&q=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22Software+Developer%22+AND+%22London%22&oq=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22Software+Developer%22+AND+%22London%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFDMZFjhZmCwZ2gAcAB4AIABLogBsAGSAQE0mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjL-dn4huDtAhUPuaQKHWX7BncQ4dUDCA0#
https://www.google.com/search?q=related:https://uk.linkedin.com/in/jack-gilbert-541a251b&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji3qP_huDtAhWAZxUIHTyfAO4QHzAIegQICxAH
https://uk.linkedin.com/in/eren-batu-999068185
```

I am trying to find a way to narrow the search to only the LinkedIn results

Comment: Try using contains linkedin //a[contains(@href,'linkedin')] .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only get `LinkedIn` result use below xpath.

Use `contains()`

```
linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="yuRUbf"]//a[contains(@href,"https://uk.linkedin.com")]')
```

Or `starts-with()`

Use

```
linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="yuRUbf"]//a[starts-with(@href,"https://uk.linkedin.com")]')
```

Comment: Hey @Kunduk ,  I tried using the `starts-with()` but I am getting the error after the scripts gets the first LinkedIn URL.                                                                                                                               `linkedin_urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="yuRUbf"]//a[starts-with(@href,"https://uk.linkedin.com")]')
print(linkedin_urls)
sleep(0.5)
for linkedin_url in linkedin_urls:
    url = linkedin_url.get_attribute("href")
    print(url)
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)
    sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)  `

Comment: The error being: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\emman\Documents\Final_Year_Project\LinkedinWebDriver.py", line 50, in <module>
    url = linkedin_url.get_attribute("href")
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 139, in get_attribute
    attributeValue = self.parent.execute_script(
  File "C:\Users\emman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in execute_script
    r

Answer (score 0):

You want to parse each string in `linkedin_url` to see if it mentions Linkedin.

```
    if 'linkedin' in linkedin_url:
        print('linkedin')
```

Basically, put the driver code that you want to be executed on Linkedin addressesd under the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the search to only the LinkedIn results you you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.yuRUbf a[href^='https://uk.linkedin.com/in']")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class="yuRUbf"]//a[starts-with(@href, 'https://uk.linkedin.com/in')]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```